# Set default language for a website?

Tags: google-chrome

I prefer to have most of my websites in default English when navigating via Google Chrome.

However, on a specific website (Amazon), I wish to set German as the default language.

Is there any way to create such an exception?

Comment: Most websites use their own Geolocation routines.  This isn’t typically handle by the browser

Answer (score 0):

Amazon.de has a language setting in its menu to select the language. Here you can specify german as language. It saves this to a cookie, so as long as you don't clear that cookie, the language should be remembered.

Comment: I may have a bug here because it gets reset randomly. I don't have anything in place that could affect the cookie setting.

Comment: Cookies can simply expire. If you don't visit the site long enough, it should reset to the default.